# in woocommerce how to set username as mobile number at registration

Tags: woocommerce, customization, registration

I am building a website using Woocommerce.By default the username is the customer username.I want to provide the users the feature to login through their phone number also. How can i do that? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. But I think not a good idea.. Imagine 2 users shares the same number.

But if you can manage to make the phone number unique, you can try something like this with WooCommerce login form.

```php
    add_filter('woocommerce_login_credentials','woocommerce_login_credentials', 10, 1);
    function woocommerce_login_credentials($creds){

        $username = trim( $_POST['username'] );
        if (is_numeric($username)){ // assumes only numeric are allowed. You can do your own logic here.
            $user = get_users(array(
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'billing_phone',
                        'value'   => $username,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                )
            ));
            $creds['user_login'] = $user[0]->data->user_login;
        }
        return $creds;
    }
```

This code is using the billing phone number. If this phone number belongs to a lot of users, only the first user that the query gets will be used. What this code do is, it gets the `user_login` of the user using the given phone number. Then use that as username to logged in. You can still use the username/email as login with this code.

**This answer demonstrate only that it can be done. I won't advice you doing so.**

Comment: it is working for email and phone no.i want only phone no login and also registered only phone